# find element that doesn't equal a string in xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

Need help in finding element that doesn't equal to a string, Here is my XML:

```
<collection >
<device>
    <name>Test</name>
    <dcs>
        <dc>
            <nodes>
                <node>
                    <name>Host1</name>
                </node>
                <node>
                    <name>test</name>
                </node>
                <node>
                    <name>testing</name>
                </node>
            </nodes>
        </dc>
        <dc>
            <nodes>
                <node>
                    <name>test</name>
                </node>
                <node>
                    <name>testing</name>
                </node>
            </nodes>
        </dc>
    </dcs>
</device>
```

XPath I have tried:

```
/collection/device/dcs/dc/nodes/node[not(contains(name,'test'))]
```

O/p:

```
 <node>
    <name>Host1</name>
</node>
```

Expected O/p:

```
<node>
      <name>Host1</name>
</node>
<node>
      <name>testing</name>
</node>
```

Actual output is ignoring testing also but that I need in output.
Can anyone help me?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To filter out nodes having inner text exactly equals certain value, use `=` operator wrapped in `not()` instead of using `contains()` in the same way  :

```
/collection/device/dcs/dc/nodes/node[not(name='test')]
```